# Does buying "The Witcher 3" on a different platform than GoG.com provide a backup copy on GoG?

Tags: the-witcher-3, gog

The previous titles of the game have provided a backup copy of the game on GoG.com. Is this also true for "The Witcher 3"? Does buying the Game on e.g. Steam or Origin provide a key for GoG?

Comment: I can tell you that (so far) the other way around is also not happening. I got a GoG key when I bought a new nVidia card, but no Steam key for this in sight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking on Steam, you cannot currently (as of 19/05/15) retrieve a CD key for the game. I cannot speak for Origin purchases, but it seems likely to be the same if utilizing the Origin infrastructure / client.

This might change in the future, but based on the previous systems (basically, entering CD keys into GoG [here](https://www.gog.com/witcher/backup)), it seems that it's not possible. Additionally, the interface linked above doesn't mentioned The Witcher 3.